# Is there a specific way to upload more than e.g 30 photos in one input, WITHOUT increasing the maximum upload size?

Tags: php, ftp, upload, image-uploading

I'm developing a page where you can upload a lot of pictures.
The idea is that you can upload as many photos as you want.
I know there is a upload limit, a memory limit, and so on...
but my server **doesn't allow me to modify php.ini.** then, my memory is 256mb and the maximum size is 25mb.
logically, I can't upload photos with more than 25mb. however, I saw that it can be done via FTP. But I'm trying to avoid that method: I couldn't make it work.

I'm thinking about switching to a server with 1gb of memory and 1tb of transfer (I don't know if that will make it work!).

Is my code wrong? if not, is there any way to upload at least 20 photos without the server going down? probably this question has already been asked but everything I found surfing forums is old and nothing worked for me. Sorry if it's a repetitive and annoying question. I will be very grateful if someone can help me.

(I removed some unimportant parts of the code because there were too many unnecessary lines, to add watermark for example)

This is for PHP7. I tried with FTP but I haven't been able to make the  transfer properly, i'm still learning.

```
if (isset($_FILES["file"]))
{

    for($x=0; $x<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]); $x++)
    {
      $file = $_FILES["file"];
      $codigosec = rand(0, 5000);
      $codigotres = rand(0, 5000);
      $nombre = $file["name"][$x];
      $tipo = $file["type"][$x];
      $ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"][$x];
      $size = $file["size"][$x];

      if ($tipo != 'image/jpeg' && $tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/png' && $tipo != 'image/gif')
      {
          echo "no es una imagen";
      }
      else
      {
          $src = (path);
          move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);      
      } 
    }
}
```

I expect find a way to upload at least 20-30 photos in a form, without depending directly on the server memory. If it can only be done with FTP, or if I have to resign myself to increasing the memory, that is a sufficient answer. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge, Without modifying php.ini (upload_max_filesize) as your required size.
->you cannot upload file if the file size less than upload_max_filesize, because if you try to upload file to the server, the server core configuration php.ini file will not allow to upload file.

->the each file size should be less than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

->the other best way to use FTP.